# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch when updating form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I have a form with cocoon including nesting fields and I get the following when updating

[image]

here is my schema

```
create_table "tournament_standings", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "position"
  t.integer "wins"
  t.integer "losses"
  t.integer "kills"
  t.integer "deaths"
  t.integer "assists"
  t.integer "prize"
  t.bigint "tournament_id", null: false
  t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.integer "team_id"
  t.integer "score"
  t.integer "goals"
  t.integer "saves"
  t.integer "shots"
  t.integer "skilld_rating"
  t.integer "category_id"
  t.index ["tournament_id"], name: "index_tournament_standings_on_tournament_id"
end
```

Here is my category select

```
<div class="mt-4">
  <%= f.label "Select tournament game", class: "block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700" %>
  <div class="mt-1 rounded-md shadow-sm">
    <%= f.select(:category_id, Category.all.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, {prompt: true, selected: :category_id}, {class: "ts_select block form-select w-full transition duration-150 ease-in-out sm:text-sm sm"}) %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This error is usually indicative of sending `update(category: 1)` instead of `update(category_id: 1)`

Comment: Yes, what @joshbrody says. Please show the data that is posted to the controller (you can find it in the logfile). Probably you gave a field in your form the incorrect name.